# how to detect a partial rectangle that can vary in size

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect a no-stop box which is shaped something like below (this picture is taken and cleaned up after applying edge detector), but can vary the size of it (sometimes it wider in length, sometimes in breath). All have similar pattern and It seem like a box. i have tried to use findcontour as well as hough line detector to detect it.

[image: edge image of box]

however the result do not seem well aat all mainly because the bottom of the box is not closed ( this happened when the box reaches a certain length )

[image]

Looking for suggestion

Some of other ideas i have
1) Look for intersection points and determine if intersection is 90 degree
2) look at HU moment and use a template image of the image for comparison

regards

Answer (score 1):

If your filtered data is always this clean, you could look into [computing oriented bounding boxes with `cv::minAreaRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect). [`cv::boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) could also work, although it appears to only give upright bounding rectangles, rather than oriented ones. Here's opencv's [tutorial for oriented bounding boxes](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do not really seem to work. the right edge of the image consists of double parallel line (though the left should be rightfully a parallel line, it don't show in this case). Upon using cv::minAreaRect, it boxed up the left edge and right edge but not the whole figure (with the x-shaped).

Comment: Prior to this, I have used a morphology dilation (size 5x5) to connect up the broken line and filled the hollow.